# Building for Win CE 4.2 in Visual Studio 2008/2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-ce, evc4

I have a legacy MFC C++ application for Win CE 4.2 (x86 ONLY) which was originally built using Embedded Visual C++ 4 (eVC4).  I need to add some functionality which comes from a C++ library which uses modern C++ features which are not supported by eVC's compiler (the VS2008 compiler supports them just fine.)

I've tried opening the solution in VS2008 and receive the error that "No platforms are available that match this project file's original platforms" despite having the SDKs installed correctly: this machine also has a functional copy of EVC4 on it.

In my research I see conflicting accounts on the internet of whether or not VS2008 can build with the CE4.2 SDK -- but since it's all x86 code I don't see why this would be an issue.

To reiterate - I don't need any ARM support, and I don't need emulators or remote debugging.  I just need to be able to build the pile of C++ files into a DLL which will fly on CE.

Anybody been down this path before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left as a crumb for those who come after --

VS2008 does not support building for WinCE.NET 4.2 using the Standard SDK for x86.

We're currently trekking back to VS2003 to get this support.

Comment: Out of curiosity, dod you try to install any x86 -based SDK, build and then copy to the device?  For example, you might try one of the eBox 2300 SDKs: http://www.embeddedpc.net/FilesDownload/tabid/66/ArticleId/15/eBox-2300.aspx

Comment: @ctackle - I tried the Windows CE 4.2 Standard SDK which works in EVC4; VS2008/2010 refused to acknowledge its presence on the machine.  The link you provided has CE5.0 SDKs, but no CE4.2 SDK which is what I need.

Comment: Thanks for the crumb. This isn't the news I was hoping for, but you've saved me a lot of futile searching.